# Why does my webcrawler not follow into the next link containing keywords

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, mechanize, urlparse

I have written a simple webcrawler that will eventually follow only news link to scrape the article text into a database. I am having problems actually following the link from the source url. This is the code so far:

```
import urlparse
import mechanize

url ="https://news.google.co.uk"

def spider(root, steps):
    urls = [root]
    visited =[root]
    counter = 0
    while counter < steps:
        step_url = scrape(urls)
        urls = []
        for u in step_url:
            if u not in visited:
                urls.append(u)
                visited.append(u)
        counter+=1
    return visited

def scrape(root):
    result_urls = []
    br = Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]
    for url in root:
        try:
            br.open(url)
            keyWords = ['news','article','business', 'world']
            for link in br.links():
                newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url,link.url)
                result_urls.append(newurl)
                [newslinks for newslinks in result_urls if newslinks in keyWords]
                print newslinks
        except:
            print "scrape error"
    return result_urls

print spider(url, 2)
```

Edit:NLTK

```
 `for text in (parse_links_text(get_links(url), d)):
    tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
    namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary=True)
    entities = re.findall(r'NE\s(.*?)/',str(namedEnt))
    descriptives = re.findall(r'\(\'(\w*)\',\s\'JJ\w?\'', str(tagged))`
```

then add to database after this.

Comment: Have you looked into `Scrapy` and it's built-in link extractors?

Comment: I have looked into scrapy but i couldn't get it to work on windows 10

Comment: I think the problem is that you just have one global `counter`, so for `steps=2` you will only visit a total of `2` URLs, instead of following URLs to a "depth" of two. Is this your problem? It's not really clear from the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't really know how to explain my problem. I'm trying to get the list of html links from google news and then visit each to parse the article text into a database.

Comment: Yes, but what is your problem? What is not working with your code? Too slow? Not the results you expected? Too few results? Do you get an error?

Comment: @tobias_k I have realised my error, `result_urls` does actually follow the links. My question should read how to parse each individual link.

Comment: Yiu don't use   `[newslinks for newslinks in result_urls if newslinks in keyWords]` at all and the blanket except is never a good idea, you have no idea if something is going wrong in your loop

Comment: So how would you suggest fixing this?

Comment: i added an answer using Beautifulsoup that should get you started, there is more to parsing the data than just pulling and following links, each site has very different html so you need to look at how html for the potential links and use the appropriate tags when parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize is not the best tool to use for what you want, this will get all the links and pull the main text from the links pages using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), we can use  a dict to create a mapping between the correct css selectors and the website names using a regex to pull the key from the link and pass the correct css to select based on that:

```
url ="https://news.google.co.uk"


import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(start):
    cont = requests.get(start).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, "lxml")
    keys = ['news','article','business', 'world']
    # links are all in the  a tag inside the esc-layout-table table
    # where the a tag class is article
    return [a["url"] for a in soup.select(".esc-layout-table a.article") if any(k in a["url"] for k in keys)]



def parse_links_text(links, css_d):
    # use regex to extract find out what page the link points to  
    # so we can pull the appropriate selector from the dict
    r = re.compile("telegraph\.|bbc\.|dailymail\.|independent\.")
    for link in links:
        print(link)
        cont = requests.get(link).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(cont)
        css = r.search(link).group()
        p = [p.text for p in soup.select(css_d[css])]
        yield p

# map each page to its correct css selector to pull the main text
d = {"dailymail.": "p.mol-para-with-font","telegraph.":"#mainBodyArea",
     "bbc.": "div.story-body p","independent.":"div.text-wrapper p"}

for text in (parse_links_text(get_links(url), d)):
    print(text)
```

That  pulls all the main body text from the articles on the *telegraph*, the *dailymail*, the *bbc* and the *independent* links. There is no magic bullet where one tag is going to get all the data you want, you will have to add any more potential selectors for other page or tweak them if the html changes.

A snippet of the output:

```
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/12199759/The-IDS-explosion-could-do-untold-damage-to-David-Camerons-reputation.html
[u' In a sense, David Cameron owes his job to Iain Duncan Smith. Without the abject failure of Mr Duncan Smith\u2019s leadership between 2001 and 2003, the Conservatives might not have reached the collective conclusion that a traditional Tory focus on issues such as Europe would not win an election and realise that, to use a Cameron phrase, they had to change to win. ', u' Mr Cameron\u2019s leadership is easily understood as a political reaction to Mr Duncan Smith\u2019s, but the two have more in common than is easily visible. Intellectually, there is a continuity between the two leaderships that is not often realised. Even as he was failing dismally as leader, Mr Duncan Smith was saying things about the party that Mr Cameron would endorse today. ', u'\n', u"Huge respect for IDS. Welfare reform must b done the right way. The electorate will not trust us again if we don't look after the vulnerable", u' So in his awful 2002 \u201cquiet man\u201d speech to the Conservative conference in Bournemouth, we find IDS outlining a vision of \u201ccompassionate conservatism\u201d, declaring: \u201cWe believe that the privileges of the few must be turned into the opportunities of the many.\u201d We also hear him telling the Tory faithful (and you had to be devoted to be at that miserable gathering) to acknowledge that many voters felt bitterly angry about the party\u2019s last spell in government: \u201cAll of us here want to remember the good things we did and there were many. But beyond this hall, people too often remember the hurt we caused and the anger they felt,\u201d he said. ', u' That is a decent exposition of what the Cameron team would, four years later, describe as the Tory \u201cbrand problem\u201d: the perception among some voters that the party governed for the privileged few at the direct expense of the less fortunate many. Changing that perception has been the most consistent objective in Mr Cameron\u2019s politics, a near-constant in a career whose successes owe much to his willingness to shift strategy and tactics according to circumstance. ', u' But \u201cdetoxifying the Tory brand\u201d is not, whatever his critics may say, simply a marketing exercise for a PM who used to work in PR. In another similarity with Mr Duncan Smith, Mr Cameron is a believer. People close to David Cameron know that what really drives and excites him is not reforming the EU (whatever he says in public, the topic bores him) or balancing the budget. Those things may dominate his Government\u2019s agenda, but friends say what raises his political passion is social reform \u2013 ensuring that people born without his privileges can share a little of the riches he has known all his life. ', u'\n', u' The origins of this feeling are hard to pinpoint with certainty, but those who have known him longest credit both his wife Samantha and their tragically short-lived first child, Ivan, with opening the eyes of a previously conventionally upper-class Conservative to the reality of life for those who suffer misfortune. ', u' So when he was, to everyone\u2019s surprise including his own, re-elected with a majority last year, the first thing Mr Cameron said was that he wished to pursue a One Nation agenda, to govern for rich and poor alike, and to make it easier for the latter to become the former. That agenda might have been recently eclipsed by Europe, and often reduced to an empty slogan, but that is where the Prime Minister\u2019s heart truly lies. For evidence, consider the series of speeches Mr Cameron gave in the early weeks of this year, focusing on social mobility, racism, and equal opportunities. ', u' I was among those who thought the speeches mostly good and impressive, though many others, including a fair few Conservatives, disagreed and took a more cynical view. But both admirers and critics alike would, I think, concede that Mr Cameron was genuine in his talk of social reform. And this is the agenda that Mr Duncan Smith is threatening with his softly spoken, hard-hitting words on The Andrew Marr Show \u2013 which were, arguably, more inflammatory than his incendiary resignation letter. ', u'\n', u'Goodbye, Iain Duncan Smith. Hello, Stephen Crabb. pic.twitter.com/fs5gscKCh3', u' Mr Duncan Smith says that Mr Cameron is not, in fact, seeking to make Britain one nation. He says the policies overseen by the Prime Minister \u2013 and let\u2019s remember that the Prime Minister, no matter how mighty he lets his Chancellor of the Exchequer become, is ultimately responsible for policy \u2013 are in the interests of the better-off and harmful to those without means or opportunity. More grave yet, he suggests his leader is indifferent to causing suffering among the poor and weak: \u201cIt just looks like we see this as a pot of money, that it doesn\u2019t matter because they don\u2019t vote for us.\u201d ', u' Coming from the man who spent six years running welfare policy, that is a potentially devastating assessment in political terms. Mr Duncan Smith makes a case for the prosecution of Mr Cameron\u2019s administration that Jeremy Corbyn could not fault. ', u'\n', u' But it is also intensely personal. Mr Duncan Smith is challenging the Prime Minister on the turf that Mr Cameron is most committed to claiming for his own. Can you really hope to go down in history as a great social-reforming premier when, in the assessment of your own welfare secretary, you have chosen to help the rich and fortunate by harming the poor and vulnerable? In this context, it is no surprise that Mr Cameron has reacted to Mr Duncan Smith\u2019s departure with true rage. (A hot temper and tendency to profanity are also things he shares with IDS, as I and several others can attest.) ', u' Amid recent events, much attention is rightly being paid to the severe damage the IDS explosion has done George Osborne\u2019s already damaged hopes of the leadership. But for Mr Cameron, this is about something else, something even more important than ambition. It is about purpose. ', u' There are already many reasons for the Prime Minister to want to win his EU referendum and run his government for a few more years. But he now has another. If Mr Cameron cannot make good on his fine words about One Nation and social mobility and equality of opportunity, and thus disprove the charges Mr Duncan Smith levels against him, then his life in politics has all been for nothing. ', u'\n\nIDS career\n']
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-35855616
[u'Iain Duncan Smith has warned that the government risks dividing society, in his first interview since resigning as work and pensions secretary.', u'He attacked the "desperate search for savings" focused on benefit payments to people who "don\'t vote for us".', u'And he told the BBC\'s Andrew Marr his "painful" decision was "not personal" against Chancellor George Osborne.', u'Downing Street said it was sorry to see Iain Duncan Smith go but was determined to help "everyone in our society".', u'BBC political correspondent Alan Soady said Mr Duncan Smith\'s interview - which followed his resignation over cuts to disability benefits on Friday - was an "absolutely blistering attack".', u'He added: "This was not just about his objections to one change in disability benefit, he was questioning the fundamental principles underpinning the government."', u'Mr Duncan Smith told the BBC he had supported a consultation on the changes to Personal Independence Payments but had come under "massive pressure" to deliver the savings ahead of last week\'s Budget.', u'The way the cuts were presented in the Budget had been "deeply unfair", he said, because they were "juxtaposed" with tax cuts for the wealthy.', u'He criticised the "arbitrary" decision to lower the welfare cap after the general election and suggested the government was in danger of losing "the balance of the generations", expressing his "deep concern" at a "very narrow attack on working-age benefits" while also protecting pensioner benefits.', u'If the focus on the working-age benefit budget continued, he said, "it just looks like we see this as a pot of money, that it doesn\'t matter because they don\'t vote for us".', u'Mr Duncan Smith, who said he felt he had become "semi-detached" from government, said the Conservatives had to return to being a party "that cares about even those who do not vote for us".', u'He said he cared "passionately" about "people who don\'t get the choices my children get" and "bringing people back in to an arena where we play daily but they do not".', u'He suggested the government was in "danger of drifting in a direction that divides society rather than unites it, and that, I think, is unfair".', u'In his interview, Mr Duncan Smith gave his version of a deteriorating relationship with the government, saying he had considered resigning last year and had "long-running" concerns about cuts imposed since May\'s general election.', u'He said the disability benefit cuts should have been part of a "much wider programme" - but after Christmas "pressure began to grow" to rush a consultation so they could feature in Wednesday\'s Budget.', u'Asked why he had not spoken out when the measures were presented to cabinet, he said he "sat silently" as he "realised the full state of what was happening" with tax cuts featuring elsewhere in the Budget.', u'After thinking "long and hard", he said he agreed to write to MPs to reassure them over the disability cuts, saying "it\'s not what it sounds like in the Budget".', u'But he said he realised in the following two days "there was no way I would able to stop this process" and resigned on Friday evening.', u'Alan Soady, BBC political correspondent', u'What pushes a cabinet minister to resign so sensationally?', u"Its origins lie partly in the rapid shift of the economic gloom-o-meter. Forecasts in December's Autumn Statement were upbeat, predicting more money rolling into the Treasury.", u'By Wednesday\'s Budget, the sunshine had turned into "storm clouds". They blew over Iain Duncan-Smith\'s department because welfare changes of recent years have so far brought in nothing like the savings originally projected.', u'IDS signed off on tightening the rules around Personal Independence Payments five days before the Budget, but now says he would rather have been allowed to wait so he could see who were the winners and losers.', u"As the row gathered momentum after the Budget, Education Secretary Nicky Morgan suggested the plans weren't set in stone.", u"Mr Duncan Smith's people disagreed, firmly believing the proposals were final. The following day, Downing Street suggested a U-turn was on the cards.", u"For IDS, it was the final straw, believing he was going to carry the can for a policy he claims he'd been bounced into prematurely. Others question his account - asking why he signed off the proposal in the first place if he was so against it.", u'Mr Duncan Smith spoke of his "love" for the Conservative Party and described claims he was trying to undermine David Cameron as "nonsense", saying he had had a "robust" conversation with the PM after telling him of his resignation.', u'Asked whether Mr Osborne would make a good prime minister, he added: "If he was to stand and if he was elected by the electorate, which is not just me it is everybody else, I would hope that he would."', u'A Number 10 spokesman said: "We are sorry to see Iain Duncan Smith go, but we are a \'one nation\' government determined to continue helping everyone in our society have more security and opportunity, including the most disadvantaged.', u'"That means we will deliver our manifesto commitments to make the welfare system fairer, cut taxes and ensure we have a stable economy by controlling welfare spending and living within our means."', u'He said more people were in work under this government with fewer "trapped" on unemployment benefits.', u'Former Lib Dem minister David Laws told Andrew Marr divisions between Mr Osborne and Mr Duncan Smith over welfare had been a "running sore throughout the last parliament".', u'He said: "George Osborne, I think it\'s fair to say, did regard the welfare budget as something of a cash cow to be squeezed in order to help to deliver deficit reduction. Iain Duncan Smith had a different view."', u"Mr Duncan Smith's resignation has divided his former ministerial team at the DWP.", u'Pensions minister Baroness Ros Altmann attacked his tenure, describing him as "exceptionally difficult" to work for, and accused him of using his resignation "to do maximum damage to the party leadership" in order to support the campaign to leave the EU.', u'But her fellow DWP minister Shailesh Vara said he was "surprised" at Baroness Altmann\'s comments, saying: "Ros\'s recollection does not accord with mine and I\'m sorry that this has all happened."', u'Disabilities minister Justin Tomlinson said the former secretary of state had "always conducted himself in a professional, dedicated and determined manner", while employment minister Priti Patel told BBC Radio 5 live it had been a "privilege" to work for him.', u'Owen Smith, Labour\'s welfare spokesman, said Mr Duncan Smith had been "very honest in explaining how George Osborne could have taken different choices" and had revealed "the fundamental unfairness at the heart of government policy".']
```

You could of course just   `p = [p.text for p in soup.select("p")]` to select all the text from the paragraphs but that is going to contain a lot of data you don't want. If you are only interested in certain pages you can also filter based on whether you find a match in the `css_d` dict using something like the following:

```
for link in links:
    cont = requests.get(link).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cont)
    css = r.search(link)
    if not css: 
       continue
    css = css.group()
    yield [p.text for p in soup.select(css)]
```

As discussed in the comments, for flexibility lxml is a great tool, to get the sections we can use the following code:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
import requests

url = "https://news.google.co.uk"



def get_sections(start, sections):
    '''Pulls the links for each sections we pass in, i.e World, Business etc...'''
    cont = requests.get(start).content
    xml = fromstring(cont, HTMLParser())
    # links are all in the  a tag inside the esc-layout-table table
    # where the a tag class is article
    secs = xml.xpath("//span[@class='section-name']")
    for sec in secs:
        _sec = sec.text.rsplit(None, 1)[0].lower().rstrip(".")
        if _sec in sections:
            yield _sec, urljoin(url, sec.xpath(".//parent::a/@href")[0])


def get_section_links(sec_url):
    ''''Get all links from individual sections.'''
    cont = requests.get(sec_url).content
    xml = fromstring(cont, HTMLParser())
    seen = set()
    for url in xml.xpath("//div[@class='section-stream-content']//a/@url"):
        if url not in seen:
            yield url
        seen.add(url)

    # set of sections we want
s = {'business', 'world', "sports", "u.k"}

for sec, link in get_sections(url, s):
    for sec_link in (get_section_links(link)):
        print(sec, sec_link)
```

So if we run the code above we get all the links from each section, a very small snippet of each section is below, there are actually  a considerable amount of links returned:

```
(u'world', 'http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/mar/21/new-york-millionaires-who-want-taxes-raised')
(u'world', 'http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-03-22/berg-turnbull%27s-only-real-option-was-bluff-and-bravado/7264350')
(u'world', 'http://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/reuters/australian-pm-takes-bold-gamble--sets-in-motion-july-2-poll/42037074')
(u'world', 'https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/checkpoint/wp/2016/03/21/these-are-the-new-u-s-military-bases-near-the-south-china-sea-china-isnt-impressed/')
(u'world', 'http://www.reuters.com/article/southchinasea-china-usa-idUSL3N16T3BH')
(u'world', 'http://atimes.com/2016/03/philippine-election-question-marks-sow-panic-in-south-china-sea/')
(u'world', 'http://www.manilatimes.net/what-if-china-attacks-bases-used-by-america/251946/')
(u'world', 'http://www.arabnews.com/world/news/898816')
(u'world', 'http://macaudailytimes.com.mo/koreas-seoul-north-korea-fires-five-short-range-projectiles.html')
(u'world', 'http://gulftoday.ae/portal/cb0e2530-0769-411d-9622-2e991191656b.aspx')
(u'world', 'http://38north.org/2016/03/aabrahamian032116/')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.irishnews.com/news/2016/03/22/news/judge-tells-madonna-and-richie-to-settle-rocco-dispute-458929/')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.marilynstowe.co.uk/2016/03/21/judge-urges-amicable-resolution-in-madonna-dispute-over-son/')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.mercurynews.com/celebrities/ci_29666212/judge-tells-madonna-and-guy-ritchie-get-it')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/celebritynews/madonna/12199922/Madonnas-UK-court-fight-with-Guy-Ritchie-over-son-Rocco-can-end-judge-rules.html')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.pbo.co.uk/news/boaty-mcboatface-leading-public-vote-to-name-200m-polar-research-ship-28429')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.theguardian.com/environment/shortcuts/2016/mar/21/from-bell-end-boaty-mcboatface-trouble-letting-public-name-things')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/boaty-mcboatface-debacle-shows-the-perils-of-crowdsourcing-opinion-from-hooty-mcowlface-to-mr-a6944801.html')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.sacbee.com/news/nation-world/world/article67322252.html')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.westerndailypress.co.uk/Jury-discharged-manslaughter-case-Thomas-Orchard/story-28964162-detail/story.html')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.exeterexpressandecho.co.uk/Breaking-Thomas-Orchard-manslaughter-trial-jury/story-28963859-detail/story.html')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/mar/21/thomas-orchard-trial-jury-discharged-judge-halts-proceedings')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/0bf3e966-ef57-11e5-9f20-c3a047354386.html')
(u'u.k', 'http://www.theweek.co.uk/london-mayor-election-2016/62681/london-mayor-election-2016-whos-in-the-running-as-starting-gun')
(u'business', 'https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/news/companies-may-soon-stop-reporting-162707837.html')
(u'business', 'http://www.theweek.co.uk/70785/why-youre-about-to-stop-getting-quarterly-reports-on-your-investments')
(u'business', 'http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-starwood-hotels-m-a-marriott-idUKKCN0WN142')
(u'business', 'http://www.reuters.com/article/us-global-oil-idUSKCN0WN00I')
(u'business', 'http://www.digitallook.com/news/commodities/commodities-oil-futures-recoup-previous-sessions-losses--1087119.html')
(u'business', 'http://news.sky.com/story/1664056/new-top-dog-at-pets-at-home-as-ceo-retires')
(u'business', 'http://money.aol.co.uk/2016/03/21/sky-tv-price-hike-shock/')
(u'business', 'http://www.nzherald.co.nz/world/news/article.cfm?c_id=2&objectid=11609694')
(u'business', 'http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3502838/The-Flying-Bum-ready-lift-World-s-largest-aircraft-Airlander-10-fitted-fins-engines-ahead-flight.html')
(u'business', 'http://www.business-standard.com/article/pti-stories/world-s-longest-aircraft-revealed-in-new-pictures-116032000569_1.html')
(u'sports', 'http://www.telegraph.co.uk/football/2016/03/21/gary-neville-consulted-roy-hodgson-on-england-delay/')
(u'sports', 'http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-3502767/Gary-Neville-leaving-Valencia-join-England-gritted-teeth-feels-like-La-Liga-club-giving-fans-chant-manager-now.html')
(u'sports', 'http://www.irishexaminer.com/sport/soccer/gary-neville-in-firing-line-as-valencia-lose-again-388634.html')
(u'sports', 'http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/tennis/top-stories/Male-tennis-players-should-earn-more-than-females-Djokovic/articleshow/51499959.cms')
(u'sports', 'http://www.sport24.co.za/soccer/livescoring?mid=23948674&st=football')
(u'sports', 'http://www.dispatch.com/content/stories/sports/2016/03/21/0321-serena-williams-rips-indian-wells-ceo.html')
(u'sports', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/35864765')
(u'sports', 'http://indianexpress.com/article/sports/football/joachim-loew-throws-max-kruse-out-of-germany-squad/')
(u'sports', 'http://www.si.com/planet-futbol/2016/03/21/max-kruse-germany-kicked-jogi-low')
(u'sports', 'http://www.dw.com/en/coach-joachim-l%C3%B6w-drops-max-kruse-from-german-national-team/a-19132035')
(u'sports', 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/35865092')
(u'sports', 'http://news.sky.com/story/1664218')
(u'sports', 'http://www.theguardian.com/business/2016/mar/21/sports-direct-founder-mike-ashley-snubs-call-mps-parliamentary-select-committee')
(u'sports', 'http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/business/sports-direct-boss-mike-ashley-7604067')
(u'sports', 'http://www.independent.ie/sport/soccer/mike-ashley-says-he-is-wedded-to-newcastle-even-if-they-go-down-34558617.html')
(u'sports', 'http://www.heraldscotland.com/sport/14373924.Michael_Carrick_praises_performance_after_United_win_Manchester_derby/')
(u'sports', 'http://www.dorsetecho.co.uk/sport/national/14373773.Michael_Carrick_hails_vital_Manchester_derby_victory/')
```

If we just return a set get_section_links we can pass that to the funtions to parse the text:

```
def get_section_links(sec_url):
    cont = requests.get(sec_url).content
    xml = fromstring(cont, HTMLParser())
    return set(xml.xpath("//div[@class='section-stream-content']//a/@url"))
```

So using *lxml* to parse using *xpaths*, for the few sites we parsed already we can add a bit more logic to catch the variations:

```
# map each page to its correct css selector to pull the main text
d = {"dailymail.": "//div[@itemprop='articleBody']//p",
     "telegraph.": "//div[@id='mainBodyArea']//p",
     "bbc.": "//div[@class='story-body']//p",
     "independent.": "//div[@class='text-wrapper']//p",
     "www.mirror.": "//*[@class='live-now-entry' or @class='lead-entry' or @itemprop='articleBody']//p"}


import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
logging.basicConfig()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def parse_links_text(links, xpath_d):
    # use regex to extract find out what page the link points to
    # so we can pull the appropriate xpath from the dict
    r = re.compile("telegraph\.|bbc\.|dailymail\.|independent\.|www.mirror.")
    for link in links:
        try:
            cont = requests.get(link).content
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logging.error(e.message)
            continue
        xml = fromstring(cont, HTMLParser())
        xpath = r.search(link)
        if xpath:
            p = "".join(filter(None, ("".join(p.xpath("normalize-space(.//text())"))
                                      for p in xml.xpath(xpath_d[xpath.group()]))))
            if p:
                yield p
        else:
            logger.debug("No match for {}".format(link))
```

Again you will have to decide what sites are possible to hit and find the correct xpaths to pull the main articles text but this should get you well along the way. I will add some logic to run the requests asynchronously  when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks ! I tried working with Beautiful soup but couldnt get it working with multiple sites. I thought mechanize would have had been ideal since I could use `br.followlink()`.

Comment: No worries,  you have a lot more flexibility with BeautifulSoup while still having a user friendly api, the code above is just an outline of what you need to do, you could easily parse the stories by category i.e world, U.K, Business etc.. using the individual links, I will add a bit more to the answer if I get some free time tomorrow. Also if you are familiar with xpath's lxml is a great tool to use also http://lxml.de/

Comment: aye I was going to put it through an nltk script and put it all into a database   I'm assuming that can be sorted by category that way aswell?

Comment: @Gaddi, yep, add an sample of how you want to group the data and I will give you an example.

Comment: So far I have been thinking of having the url with datetime then each word sorted into types so I can distinguish the subject locations etc.

Comment: Add an example to your question and I will use it

Comment: Added the nltk code, I havent been able to test it properly as I had to re-download the nltk_data files.

Comment: I meant in regard to how there are business articles, world articles etc.. Do you plan on categorising those when you parse or are you treating it all as one piece of data just the dates being unique? Also can you use python 3 to do the parsing and get the source?

Comment: I was planning to try and sort by the general subjects as you listed. I was thinking of having the url as the starting point and having the date and contents following it. I haven't actually used python 3 would this be more beneficial?

Comment: @Gaddi, I asked about python3 as there are nice builtin methods to run async tasks, we can do the same with some libs for python2. So we will try separate into groups like they have on the site Sports » , Entertainment » etc..? Or by site? Also can you use lxml?

Comment: I will have a more in depth look is it easy to port form 2.7 to 3? I'm uncertain how it should be grouped now pretty unfamiliar to databases in general. I haven't really used it apart from making the soup in beautifulsoup, the documentation looks fairly comprehensive.

Comment: lxml is great, it is very powerful especially when matching partial patterns. I will throw something together that will group by sports etc..

Comment: It seems to go more in depth that bs4. Thanks again for all your help with this !

Comment: No worries, I added how to get all the links by section so it should be easy categorise and add to a db, there are a whole lot of links to parse so it will take a bit of work to cover all the xpaths, of course if you want to only parse certain domains it will be easy filter out using the xpath dict, you would also want to use the full domain for the regex and dict keys so you don't match other strings.